# How to remove query string from static resource?

Tags: query-string, drupal-8

I've tried it with
https://www.drupal.org/project/remove_querystring_from_static_resource

But it doesn't work well for me .

How can I achieve that programmatically?

The following is the test result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This trouble is usually encountered when static resources (eg. images, css & javascript files) are accessed using a query string.

```
Eg: http://example.com/image.png?something=test
```

Those query strings are used for avoiding browser caching. Their values are changed, so the browser should do a new request instead of getting cached resource.

You should remove those query strings (`?something=test` in my example) and use some suitable `Cache-Control` headers.

**Edit:**
Try this code.

Replace THEMENAME with your theme name.

```
/**
 * Implements template_process_html().
 * Remove Query Strings from CSS & JS filenames
 */
function THEMENAME_process_html( &$variables) {
    $variables['styles'] = preg_replace('/\.css\?[^"]+/', '.css', $variables['styles']);
    $variables['scripts'] = preg_replace('/\.js\?[^"]+/', '.js', $variables['scripts']);
}

/**
 * Implement hook_image_style
 * Override theme image style to remove query string.
 * @param $variables
 */
function THEMENAME_image_style($variables) {
    // Determine the dimensions of the styled image.
    $dimensions = array(
        'width' => $variables['width'],
        'height' => $variables['height'],
    );
    image_style_transform_dimensions($variables['style_name'], $dimensions);
    $variables['width'] = $dimensions['width'];
    $variables['height'] = $dimensions['height'];
    // Determine the URL for the styled image.
    $variables['path'] = image_style_url($variables['style_name'], $variables['path']);
    // Remove query string for image.
    $variables['path'] = preg_replace('/\?.*/', '', $variables['path']);
    return theme('image', $variables);
}
```

Comment: I inserted "<meta http-equiv = 'cache-control' content = 'no-cache'>" to header but query strings are still existing . which directive should I use?

Comment: That line doesn't help you. Remove the highlighted parts: http://prntscr.com/i90msq

Comment: Yeah.but how to remove the highlighted parts that's what exactly I want to know. I've tried to remove it by js. but it's useless

Comment: Removing them using JS does not make sense. Resources are already loaded. See my edited answer.

Comment: I used that code before using js code .it doesn't work ....., i think i'm going to give up.but thank you very much .

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved the issue with this code:

```
    use Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface;

    /**
    * Implements hook_css_alter().
    */

    function bootstrap_css_alter(&$css, AttachedAssetsInterface $assets){
        foreach ($css as &$file) {
            if ($file['type'] != 'external') {
            $file['type'] = 'external';
            $file['data'] = '/' . $file['data'];
            }
        }

     }


     /**
     * Implements hook_js_alter().
     */

    function bootstrap_js_alter(&$javascript, AttachedAssetsInterface $assets){

        foreach ($javascript as &$file) {
            if ($file['type'] != 'external') {
            $file['type'] = 'external';
            $file['data'] = '/' . $file['data'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Put this code to your yourthemename.theme file.
it works perfect on drupal 8 
Hope this help you guys.